# How to import Sparx EA requirements as TFS work items to TFS

Tags: tfs, enterprise-architect

I am looking for a tool that integrate EA with TFS 2010 where the requirements and use cases are defined in EA and synchronize them to TFS as TFS work items/user stories.

Ideally when the requirements/use cases are updated in EA, the title & description of the associated TFS work item/use case are also updated on the synchronization.

I tried MDG integration but it supports only from TFS to EA, but not from EA to TFS.

Have anyone tried similar integration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to write some custom code to do this task yourself.  TFS has a very rich API to allow you to programmatically interface with it.  I would store the TFS WI ID with each EA requirement. Then have some custom code that scans your EA requirements (nightly/hourly), and those without a TFS WI ID should be created in TFS using the API, those with a pre-existing WI ID can be validated that title and desc match and if not use the API to update TFS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dylan, not sure EA expose the API that returns list of requirements as well as update service for TFS ID.